# Combining boolean and if

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean

I have just started my journey with Java. I would like to write a code which will ask user to make a choice between two lanugages: English and Spanish. 
User will type ENG and there should be "Hello my friend" printed or user will type ESP and there should be "Ola amigo" printed. If user will type something else there question will appear to make a correct choice again. Below is my code so far.. could you please help?

`

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Make a language choice: ENG for ENGLISH or ESP for SPANISH");


        boolean ENG;  // determines English language
        boolean ESP;  //determines Spanish language

        if(ENG) {

            System.out.println("Hello my friend");
        }

        if(ESP) {
            System.out.println("Ola amigo");
        }

        else {
            System.out.println ("Make a language choice: ENGLISH or SPANISH");
        }
```

`

Answer (score 1):

try using a while() loop for input validation

```
import java.util.*;

    public class Main
    {
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Make a language choice: ENG for ENGLISH or ESP for SPANISH");
            String enteredAnswer=scan.nextLine();

            while(!(enteredAnswer.equals("ENG")||enteredAnswer.equals("ESP")))
            {
                System.out.println("Make a language choice:ENG for ENGLISH or ESP for SPANISH");
                enteredAnswer=scan.nextLine();
            }
            if(enteredAnswer.equals("ENG")) {

                System.out.println("Hello my friend");
            }

            if(enteredAnswer.equals("ESP")) {
                System.out.println("Ola amigo");
            }

        }



}
```

Comment: "If user will type something else there question will appear to make a correct choice again"

Comment: Thank you for help!

Comment: glad I helped you, please accept this as an answer if I solved your coding problem also I suggest buy a book entitled "Java Programming" by Joyce Farrell to further enhance your knowledge about java

Answer (score 1):

```
String answer = scanner.next();
boolean ENG = ("ENG").equals(answer);  // determines English language
boolean ESP = ("ESP").equals(answer);  //determines Spanish language
```

Comment: It's spelled "Hola", not "Ola".